# Bokeh - Div not updating

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a Bokeh application running with the Bokeh server. I am trying to update a div text based on a date range slider. It does update the first few times but when the slider goes to the last date it is available and then back the text does not get updated it remains stale. Any ideas why that is the case?
In the print statement I can see the text being correct but it does not get reflected in the UI.

```
   def update_div(attr, old, new):
            value = daterangeslider.value
            start = pd.to_datetime(value[0], unit='ms')
            end = pd.to_datetime(value[1], unit='ms')
            newdata = updatedata(start, end)
            div.text = updatetext(newdata)
            print(div.text)
    
    start = Datetime(2020,1,1)
    end = Datetime(2021,1,1)
    daterangeslider = DateRangeSlider(value=(start, end),
                            start=start, end=end)
    newdata = updatedata(start, end)
    div.text = updatetext(newdata) 
    div = Div(text = txt)
    daterangeslider.on_change('value', partial(update_div))
```